# jQuery styling disappears after ajax call

Tags: jquery

so i am trying to ensure my styling applied by jQuery will remain after ajax calls. It is a product colour filter, and the options are to Apply Filter or Clear Filter. When either of those are clicked, the styling disappears.

I thought the ajaxComplete function might have done the trick, but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is my code:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', function () { ?>

    <script>
       var my_colours = function ( $ ) {            
          
       jQuery('.bapf_body ul > li').each(function() {
        var getCol = jQuery('input', jQuery(this)).data('name');
        var imageUrl = "https://website/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/" + getCol + ".jpg";
       jQuery(".bapf_img_span", jQuery(this)).css('background-image', 'url("' + imageUrl + '")');
        console.log('CSS background-image =', jQuery(".bapf_img_span", jQuery(this)).css('background-image'));  
});
       }
</script>
<?php }, 5 ); 

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'cv_theme_custom_script', 999999 );
function cv_theme_custom_script() { ?>
<script>
    jQuery( document ).ready( function ( $ ) {
        my_colours( $ );
    } );
</script>
<?php
}


add_action( 'wp_head', function () { ?>
    <script>
    
    $.ajaxComplete(function () {
        // trigger the other JS snippet again after AJAX.
        my_colours( $ );
    });
    
    </script>
    <?php }, 9999999 );
```

EDIT: It now works, I wasn't calling the ajaxComplete in proper format,

it should be:

jQuery( document ).ajaxComplete(function () { ...

Comment: Please show the rendered HTML and JavaScript. This code is very hard to read with the mixed PHP, HTML, and JavaScript code. Also, please take a stab at tidying the code a bit. If you put it in a Stack Snippet (icon looks like `<>` in the editor toolbar), it has a Tidy button that can help.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: hi guys, i edited my question, i was calling the ajaxComplete wrong. it now works. thank you

Comment: Hey thanks for this @mir this is exactly what I was looking for! I was able to read your answer correctly! forget those other dusty commenters!